# One simple question on wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I to start learn wxPython is usin YouTube, I watched 14 tutorials,
and could not find more video tutorials on this program. Where can I find more information about this program
Please Help me! Dont delete this question. Thanks :)

Comment: How about the website? http://www.wxpython.org/ :)

Comment: Official site has little information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone I know has learned in the following way:  They look for a simple online tutorial (*e.g.*, [here](http://www.wxpython.org/tutorial.php) or [here](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/firststeps/), or [more generally](http://www.google.com/search?q=wxpython+tutorial)) and learn how to make simple frames and dialogs and add a few simple things into these windows (like a button), and how to handle simple events (like a button click).  Then, they look over the demo (found on the wxPython download page) to find the widgets they like, and put these in the main window.

Answer (score 0):

The [wxPython in Action](http://www.manning.com/rappin/) book is fantastic, a bit old I think... but it covers everything from how wxPython works under the hood to good coding practices!

If you cannot get the book then check tom10's suggestion, particularly the [wxPython Tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/) at zetcode.com, it's great!